# Convert a minute of day (such as 192) to 3:12 AM (or 03:12) in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm using a web API that sends back time in the format of "minute of the day". For instance, it returns 192 for 3:12 AM (or 03:12 for 24 hour time).

Is there a way to format the minute of the day to the better looking 3:12 AM/03:12?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use NSDateFormatter for this

Comment: Thanks Cristik, i figured NSDateFormatter could handle this, but I can't figure it out in the class reference. Is there an example that you know to show it?

Comment: There are lots of questions on this matter, check them, you mind find some useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+nsdateformatter+

Answer (score 4):

get beginning of today

```
let today = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
```

add 192 min

```
let date = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Minute, value: 192, toDate: today, options: [])
```

print with short style

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
print(formatter.stringFromDate(date!))
```

result

```
3:12 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

The most comfortable way to achieve that is using the `NSDateComponentsFormatter`. You specify units that you want in the output (`.Hour`, `.Minute`) and the time interval in seconds... Plenty of options, it is worth breezing through the documentation on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Below is complete example

```
     let myDateComponent = NSDateComponents()
  myDateComponent .year = 2016
  myDateComponent .month = 1
  myDateComponent .day = 11
  myDateComponent .hour = totalMinutes / 60
  myDateComponent .minute = totalMinutes % 60
  myDateComponent .second = 0

let calendarDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(myDateComponent )!


/***** NSDateFormatter Part *****/

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle

let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(calendarDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to get into all of the date component stuff. This is simple:

```
let totalMinutes = 192
let hours = (totalMinutes / 60)
let adjustedHours = hours % 12 == 0 ? 12 : hours
let minutes = totalMinutes % 60
let ampm = hours < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"
print("\(adjustedHours):\(minutes) \(ampm)")  // Prints 3:12 AM
```

I'd actually wrap it in a function and account for the military time factor:

```
func formatTimeFromMinutes(totalMinutes: Int, militaryTime: Bool) -> String {
    let hours = totalMinutes / 60
    let minutes = totalMinutes % 60

    if militaryTime {
        let prefix = (0..<10).contains(hours) ? "0" : ""
        return "\(prefix)\(hours):\(minutes)"
    } else {
        let adjustedHours = hours % 12 == 0 ? 12 : hours
        let ampm = hours < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"
        return "\(adjustedHours):\(minutes) \(ampm)"
    }
}
```